# How do I build code out of a tutorial repo that has many examples (in Visual Studio/C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, solution

### How do I build sample code, split into folders in a repo, from a class or tutorial, in Visual Studio?

So - I'm pretty much a noob at C#, I've gone through a lot of tutorials and browsed through some large C# projects from work and built them, and done some other minor things. I'm going through a course on writing testable code on [*Pluralsight*](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/writing-testable-code/description). He has a public Github repo for the code examples, [*writing-testable-code*](https://github.com/matthewrenze/writing-testable-code).  I connected to the repo and downloaded it okay into a local Git repo. I was able to download all the packages from NuGet and they are all showing as the version he used (a few have updates, but I figured updating might break things).

**I can't figure out how to run this code, build it, or run the tests in it.**

### What I tried so far

My issue is - I open the solution, and there are a bunch of files and folders - each module/chapter is split into folders (i.e. Module1/Easy, Module1/Hard, Module2/Easy, etc.). **I want to build the Module1/Easy folder, including unit test examples, and run the tests**.

When reviewing Module1/Easy, it has 3 files that should build okay - the program.cs has a main() and looks like a console app, the Calculator.cs has a simple class, and the CalculatorTests.cs has unit tests built for Nunit. The solution has NUnit, Castle.core, and things from later modules (Moq, AutoMoq, Unity, Ninject, etc.). It didn't seem to have a VS runner, so I added Nunit3TestAdapter - the guy in the course has resharper installed, which I don't, and he was using the Resharper test runner, which would explain why he didn't include it.

I tried setting the "Module1/Easy/Project.cs" file the "Set as Startup Item", since it has a main and looks setup as a console app.  However, running it (the "Start" button turned into a "Program.cs" button), it fails saying it can't run a dll. The tests aren't showing up in the Test Explorer like some other small projects I've built from examples.

### What's the right way to do this?

I'm not sure where to go from here. On the Build menu is only a "Build Solution" and one about Code Analysis - I'm used to a lot more options here.  It feels like I have to turn this folder into a project, maybe?  I can always reinstall the packages - but what is the best solution here?

I've run into this before on other book, tutorial, or class repos, but finally decided to figure out how to get this one working. I appreciate any help!

### Notes

1. I'm running Visual Studio Community 2017 at the moment.
2. I can post some of the files, but the repo is publically available, and not sure exactly what to post to help.

### Progress from comments and answers

1. Per Biker-Dude's answer, I switched the project to build a console app rather than a dll, and now I get a compile-time error for having multiple entry points (i.e. every module and sub folder has its own Main() function and should probably be a separate project).
2. After #1, I removed all folders but one from the solution, it will then compile, run the tests, etc. - but I eventually want to be able to at least separately compile every sub-folder - what's the best way?

Comment: For a beginner's course this is madly confusing: one project with multiple entry points and the same single project is also used for testing? Not good..

Comment: I think he was using the repo as a means to just dump all the code examples in one go - the thing is, I've run across this same issue several times in the past. I generally just browsed the code in the repo or already had a separate project/solution on my own, so I just copied certain things over. But I've always been bothered that I didn't know the right way to deal with this kind of a situation. It's possible the answer is to just download the folders and build a separate solution and build it properly with separate projects from each folder.  If that's right, I'm okay with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of BikerDude's answer and stijn's comments, I was eventually able to play around with this and get some things working.

**First of all, don't try to exclude any folders in this situation**, that will just make things worse!  They will still be in your underlying folder/repo, just won't be showing up in your solution anywhere, and you won't be able to create a new folder with the same name (weird decision...). And you'll have to add them back in as individual files - I think.

### The best solution (so far)

The best solution seems to be:

1. Create a new project for each buildable set of files in the solution (in my case, at least one project per "module" folder). I used the ".Net framework console app" project type (right click on the solution, use Add/New Project) to get things to work, but this would depend on the particular course or tutorial repo you downloaded.
2. Move the folder or sub-folder that has the files you want to build out of the main solution and into the new project - you can click and drag to move it.
3. Visual Studio will make an empty, pre-formatted file in your project that you likely have to delete - for .Net apps, this is the "Program.cs" file in C#.  For one of my folders this file already existed, and I had to delete the new one in order to build.  Another folder from a different module was setup more like a library and couldn't build standalone, but this procedure did get me to being able to build the files and that allowed the unit tests to show up in the test explorer and run the tests successfully (which was the main point of that module).
4. Go to the solution and right-click and choose "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution". As long as all the packages are installed for the main solution, then they will all show up in the list of Installed Packages (you might need to click on the "Installed" tab). You can click on each package in turn, then on the right you can checkmark the new project, and the "Install" button should be available - click it.  Repeat for all the packages to install them all.  Note that you can cut out some repetition here if you create all the projects you need first, then you can install all of them at the same time in this step (i.e. checkmark all the new projects at once instead of reopening the package manager each time).
5. You might have to fix the NameSpace - it should be consistent within the files/folders you transferred from the original solution, but if you add any new files to play with things, the Namespace for it will likely not match, and to see classes, etc. in the original files, you'll have to update your Namespace on the new files.
6. Per BikerDude's answer - After transferring everything to new projects, if you keep anything in the original project that came with the solution, it might not be trying to build the right type of item.  You may be able to fix that by right-clicking the project, selecting properties, and adjusting the "output type", but it may not have the options you need.  If it doesn't, just create a new project with the right type and transfer the files as above.

After following the above steps, I was able to build each new project I created, using the original files from folders that I moved.  Mainly I just needed to build, which enabled all the unit tests that this tutorial/class was focused on, but this allowed me to build the console apps as well, when present.

Thanks for the help from all in pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be that the project must have the output type set to class libraries. Browse through the solution tree and:

> Select your class's project> right click > Properties > Application >
>   Output Type > Console Application/ Windows Application.

This should fix it, if the other things are set up properly.

Comment: That got me to the next step, but now it fails with "multiple entry points error" - which is kind of what I expected.  Since each module has multiple "mini-projects", each with it's own Main() function, I somehow need to now narrow the project down to just one of the folders.  It's like each folder should be it's own project, then I could just build the project I'm interested in.  That being said, the test class can build and run now!  :)

Comment: The only thing you can do here to get 1 exe out of it is exclude all but 1 program.cs file from the project. Or create X projects, one for each exe.

Comment: LightCC you can right click > hit unload the useless projects if that makes it better for your case. Also, you can convert the other projects into dependencies, and still use methods from the various classes. 

In case you definitely want multiple exe files(Lets say you want to do application multithreading), I need to do some research and get back to you.

Also, don't hit start, compile and go to the bin, then run those exe files individually. If you want to debug them, add a Debugger.Launch() command into your code before compilation.

Comment: So, I did remove every module folder and the Module1/Hard folder, so just Module1/Easy was left, and then it compiles okay.  It's much less clear how to add the other folders back in (it seems to only want to add individual files, and I can't recreate new folders with the same names as the removed folders).  Should I make separate projects for each sub folder and then add them individually into each project?  Then I can build projects individually and control them at that level, right?

Comment: I can right click on the (Solution or Folder or Project) in the solution tree and still add>New folder. 

Can't you?

Comment: Yes, I can add a folder, as long as it doesn't have the same name as a folder that is already in that directory. When I "excluded from project", the folders and files are still there, invisible, and it won't let me recreate a folder that has the same name... Not ideal workflow!

Comment: @LightCC You are right, excluding removes the compile-command for the particular items from your solution. 

I would always recommend establishing version control before you start messing with original code, this makes it possible to revert any changes that you make.

Also, are you using Build>Build Solution to build the solutions, or are you doing start to compile and run?

Comment: Yes, I did clone the repo from Github to my PC, and I was commiting and branched a time or two as I played with things.  I actually just reset everything and restarted after I figured out what was happening.  Doing that has helped me learn Git a little better. :) For Module 1, I could compile a console app, but the rest appear to be just class libraries, so I'm building them (not starting), and this is recognizing all the units tests, and I'm able to run them, which is the main point of this tutorial.